# java hashMap Adjacency Lists graph partition

Tags: java, graph, hashmap, partition, adjacency-list

I have a HashMap with:

```
Key,Value
A,C
B,C
C,D
E,F
```

This is an Adjacency List. with a graph with two partition, where the first partition contains the nodes {A,B,C,D} and the second partition is {E,F}.

Problem: Given a HashMap that represents an Adjacency List return the partitions.

In other words:

```
Input: {[A,C],[B,C],[C,D],[E,F]}
Output: {[A,B,C,D],[E,F]}
```

Some solution/algorithm in Java to solve this ???

Ps: Not limited to Java, any help are welcome :)

Tks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any graph traversal technique for this (BFS or DFS).

For example, if you are using BFS :

- Start from any node (lets say X).
- After you have visited all nodes connected to this node, check if all nodes of graph were visited. If you encounter a node that was not visited, start a new BFS from this node, This will be your second partition.
- And so on...

In your case, if you start BFS from A, it will visit [C, B, D]. This is the 1st partition.

Now you check if there are unvisited nodes in graph (E). So, now you start a BFS from E and all nodes which you visit are in 2nd partition.

Answer (score 0):

IMO The best solution is [Union-Find algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)

```
public class UnionFind {
    Map<String, String> parents = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> representantElements = new HashMap<>();

    public void union(String p0, String p1) {
        String cp0 = find(p0);
        String cp1 = find(p1);
        if (!cp0.equals(cp1)) {
            int size0 = representantElements.get(cp0);
            int size1 = representantElements.get(cp1);
            if (size1 < size0) {
                String swap = cp0;
                cp0 = cp1;
                cp1 = swap;
            }
            representantElements.put(cp0, size0 + size1);
            parents.put(cp1, cp0);
            representantElements.put(cp1, 0);
        }
    }

    public String find(String p) {
        if (!representantElements.containsKey(p)){
            representantElements.put(p, 1);
            return p;
        }
        String result = parents.get(p);
        if (result == null) {
            result = p;
        } else {
            result = find(result);
            parents.put(p, result);
        }
        return result;
    }

    public Set<Set<String>> getPartitions() {
        Map<String, Set<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
        representantElements.forEach((key, value) -> {if (value > 0) {result.put(key, new HashSet<>(value));};});
        representantElements.forEach((key, value) -> result.get(find(key)).add(key));
        return new HashSet<>(result.values());
    }

    public static Set<Set<String>> partitions(String[][] pairs) {
        UnionFind groups = new UnionFind();
        for (String[] pair : pairs) {
            if (pair.length > 1) {
                String first = pair[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < pair.length; i++) {
                    groups.union(first, pair[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        return groups.getPartitions();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[][] elements = {{"A","C"},{"B","C"},{"C","D"},{"E","F"}};
        for (Set<String> partition : partitions(elements)) {
            System.out.println(partition);
        }
    }
}
```

It prints:

```
[A, B, C, D]
[E, F]
```

Comment: Now I'll try to apply this to a 

Map<String, Set<String>> elements 

TKS A LOT !!!!